# Backing NTFS hard drive to a Linux distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, hard-drive, ntfs

I want to move to Linux (Ubuntu more specifically) and also bought a new hard drive. What I'm not really sure about is if I put my old hard drive on an external case, then install Ubuntu on the new one and configure, etc... Can I easily access my old one (which is now an external hard drive)? Will I have no problems accessing my partitions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu can read and write to NTFS drives using the ntfs-3g project. It's less efficient and more CPU-intensive than an in-kernel driver, but the data will be fully accessible as long as you're not using features like encryption.

Ubuntu NTFS HOWTO:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=217009

Comment: +1, ntfs-3g works with RHEL-based systems as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern distro can handle NTFS just fine. I regularly access my NTFS partitions when booted to 10.04 a usb drive would be no different. It really should be just plug and go.

Comment: RHEL & its cousins unfortunately still don't ship out-of-the-box with NTFS support.